# Background fetch never gets called

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I know there are hundreds of topics out there concerning the background fetch on iOS. I simply cannot solve my problem to get the background fetch for my app to work. It is absoulutely substantial for the outcome of my app to have a working background fetch. My background fetch works fine on the simulator via Debug -> Simulate Background fetch and also on device with the special scheme setting: "Launch due to a background fetch event". I know that it doesn´t gets executed when the user is force quitting the app. I tried to lock the iPhone and wait for hours then unlock it to try to trigger the background fetch. Nothing happens. Actually everything works fine but the background fetch simply NEVER gets executed on my iPhone. I know that iOS has a special algorithm for calling background threads so a little patient is needed. But after 2 months of waiting for a background fetch to happen automatically I don´t have patients anymore. What I did:

1. App capabilites: Background fetch activated
2. Info.plist: Required background modes: App downloads content from the network
3. App delegate:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:2.0];
    return YES;
}

- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    //Do my stuff
   completionHandler (UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Comment: I did exactly the same steps in my current app. The only thing that differs from my code is the function:
 [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
The UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum is the minimum interval value allowed and managed by the system. Probably 2.0 is too slow and could be the problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: Also, when the app launches in the background, it has about thirty seconds at its disposal to complete all of the required tasks and call the completion handler. If this time limit is exceeded, the app will become suspended even if the task is not finished.

Comment: I also tried what Javier Flores Font said. I will try it again. My background task is very short, it´s just parsing one page which takes maybe maximum 10 seconds. It´s very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

Did you check out to go Settings->General->background app refresh and check if its enabled?
It could be the problem...

Comment: Yes it was eneabled. I did another version with FetchIntervalMinimum and received one background fetch yesterday. Yeah! Even though I already tried this. Now it seems to work. Programming is strange.